# Extract everything from a specific part of a string to the end of the line

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a file abcd.txt
In that file the contents are,

hello 123 [1231 12312 123]1231231
hello world[3r45t sds]6542
123 213 135
4234 gdfg gfd 32
sd23 234 sdf 23
hi hello[234 23423]561
hello hi[123 123]985

I want to print the string which is after the '[' character.
My output should be:
1231231
6542
561
985

Comment: What did you try? The regex for this would be pretty basic.

Comment: I tried this 
file = open('gis.dat')
list = []
for line in file:
 line = line.rstrip()
        if re.search('[0-9]', line):
                                list.append(line.split(']')[0])

Comment: do you mean after the ']' character?

Comment: yes everything on the line after [

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward. Use the `.find()` method to get the index of "]" and then get the last few characters of the line with the list accessor syntax. `string[a:]` will get the substring of "string" that starts at "a" and ends at the end of the string.

```
file_contents = """hello 123 [1231 12312 123]1231231
hello world[3r45t sds]6542
123 213 135
4234 gdfg gfd 32
sd23 234 sdf 23
hi hello[234 23423]561
hello hi[123 123]985 """

file_lines = file_contents.split("\n")
for line in file_lines:
    bracket_index = line.find("]")
    end_of_line = line[bracket_index + 1:]
    if bracket_index != -1:
        print(end_of_line)
```

Comment: In case of multiple brackets use `rfind("]")`

Comment: This works when the contents are in the paragraph form. When i tried opening the file it doesnt seem to work
file = open('gis.dat')   
                file_lines = file.split("\n")   
                for line in file_lines:   
                        bracket_index = line.rfind("]")    
                        end_of_line = line[bracket_index + 1:]    
                        if bracket_index != -1:    
                                print(end_of_line)

Comment: Could be different line endings, are you on windows? Try printing the line on every loop iteration

Comment: Actually looks like you're not reading the file, change the first line to `file = open('gis.dat').read()`

Answer (score 0):

This works if you want the code after the ']'. If you want between '[' and ']', can modify so.

```
f=open(location+'abcd.txt')

data={}
i=0
for line in f:
    data[i]=line
    i+=1

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    a=data[i]
    start=0
    end=len(a)

    for j in range(0,len(a)):
        if a[j]=='[':
            start=j
        elif a[j]==']':
            end=j

    print a[end+1:]
```

I am checking for '[' because I initially thought you were looking for the interval.